# "package does not exit" error while compiling project after converted from Eclipse

Tags: android, eclipse, android-studio, gradle

I've converted an Eclipse project for AndroidStudio then I got some errors "package does not exits", it package is library module.

library project's gradle scripts as follows.

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.library'
android {
    compileSdkVersion 23
    buildToolsVersion "23.0.1"
    defaultConfig {
        minSdkVersion 9
        targetSdkVersion 22
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0.0"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled true
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard.cfg'
        }
        debug {
            minifyEnabled false
        }
    }
    lintOptions {
        abortOnError false
    }
    useLibrary 'org.apache.http.legacy'
}

dependencies {
    compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:22.0.0'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:9.0.0'
}
```

and the project's gradle

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 23
    buildToolsVersion "23.0.1"
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx"
        minSdkVersion 9
        targetSdkVersion 22
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0.0"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled true
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard.cfg'
        }
        debug {
            minifyEnabled false
        }
    }
    lintOptions {
        abortOnError false
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:23.0.0'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:9.0.0'
    compile project(':library')
}
```

It's weird because IDE does not show any errors while coding and can import package properly but when I try to "run" the project, then error occurs.

I would appreciate it if someone could solve this problem.

## Edited

Project Structure is like below.
- app (com.sample.apps)
- library (com.sample.library)

Actual Error Messages

```
package com.sample.library.xxx does not exits // <- My Custom Class. There are hundreds of errors.
```

Gradle Errors

```
:app:compileDebugJavaWithJavac - is not incremental (e.g. outputs have changed, no previous execution, etc.).
Note: Some input files use or override a deprecated API.
Note: Recompile with -Xlint:deprecation for details.
Note: Some messages have been simplified; recompile with -Xdiags:verbose to get full output
100 errors

:app:compileDebugJavaWithJavac FAILED

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':app:compileDebugJavaWithJavac'.
> Compilation failed; see the compiler error output for details.

* Try:
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.

BUILD FAILED

Total time: 4.344 secs
```

## Solved

I solved this by using product flavors.
This is because library project is going to apply proguard and that's why application project can't find package.

I changed 'com:android:library' to 'com:android:application' and move app project as product flavors.

Comment: can you please show your project structure?

Comment: And the actual run output, including the error message?

Comment: I added structures and error messages.